# ¿Cómo editar registro que contiene un select?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phpmyadmin, php7

Estoy desarrollando un crud en php, con ajax y js

Cuándo doy de alta un registro en el modal correspondiente, tengo un select en el cual indico la categoría a la que pertenece el cuál almacena en la tabla estatus la opción seleccionada.

**Mi problema viene cuando quiero editar algún registro el select me lo trae vacio**. ¿Cómo debo hacer para que, al editar el registro el select muestre la opción que seleccion al momento que se dio de alta el registro.

Espero puedan entenderme, les comparto el codigo donde mando a llamar la funcion editar.

```js
//Editar
    $(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function () {
        opcion = 2;//editar
        fila = $(this).closest("tr");
        id = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text()); //capturo el ID                    
        folio = fila.find('td:eq(1)').text();
        nombre = fila.find('td:eq(2)').text();
        apellido = fila.find('td:eq(3)').text();
        direccion = fila.find('td:eq(4)').text();
        descripcion_domicilio = fila.find('td:eq(5)').text();
        telefono = fila.find('td:eq(6)').text();
        num_contrato = fila.find('td:eq(7)').text();
        fecha_inicio = fila.find('td:eq(8)').text();
        fecha_final = fila.find('td:eq(9)').text();
        cuadrilla = fila.find('td:eq(10)').text();
        estatus = fila.find('td:eq(11)').text();
        console.log(estatus)
        observaciones = fila.find('td:eq(12)').text();
        encargado_cuadrilla = fila.find('td:eq(13)').text();
        otra_descripcion = fila.find('td:eq(14)').text();
        $("#folio").val(folio);
        $("#nombre").val(nombre);
        $("#apellido").val(apellido);
        $("#direccion").val(direccion);
        $("#descripcion_domicilio").val(descripcion_domicilio);
        $("#telefono").val(telefono);
        $("#num_contrato").val(num_contrato);
        $("#fecha_inicio").val(fecha_inicio);
        $("#fecha_final").val(fecha_final);
        $("#cuadrilla").val(cuadrilla);
        $("#estatus").val(estatus);
        $("#observaciones").val(observaciones);
        $("#encargado_cuadrilla").val(encargado_cuadrilla);
```

Aqui muestro parte del codigo, que esta dentro del modal donde muentro las categorias  al aque pertenece el select

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-form-label">Estatus</label>
                                <select name="status" id="estatus" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option selected>eleccione una opción</option>
                                    <option value="1">Pendiente</option>
                                    <option value="2">En Proceso</option>
                                    <option value="3">Terminado</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar esto:

```
  $("#estatus option:contains(" + estatus + ")").attr('selected', '')
```

donde:

- **$("#estatus option:contains(" + estatus + ")")** apunta al **option** el cual contiene el mismo texto que la columna que recoges con la variable `estatus`.
- **attr('selected', '')** le agrega el atributo *selected* al **option** precedido.

Aquí dejo un snippet de ejemplo:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function() {
  opcion = 2; //editar
  fila = $(this).closest("tr");
  nombre = fila.find('td:eq(0)').text();
  estatus = fila.find('td:eq(1)').text();
  $("#nombre").val(nombre);
  $("#estatus option:contains(" + estatus + ")").attr('selected', '')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>juan</td>
    <td>En Proceso</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btnEditar">
        Editar
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <input id="nombre">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-form-label">Estatus</label>
        <select name="status" id="estatus" class="form-control" required>
          <option selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
          <option value="1">Pendiente</option>
          <option value="2">En Proceso</option>
          <option value="3">Terminado</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: si me recupera la información pero cuando le doy en editar, mi select aparece las opciones duplicadas.

Comment: Perdona, tienes razón, acabo de corregir mi respuesta, actualiza esta página y pruébala de nuevo.

Comment: hola tu código me funciono bien, pero ahora tengo un problema, cuando intento editar algún registro, me aparece el último registro que edite, tengo que presionar varias veces F5 para poder editar otro registro, y en ocasiones no me recupera el valor. Alguna forma de poder corregir ese error?

Comment: mmm... no estoy seguro de entenderte... si acaso abre otra pregunta con tu código actual con varios registros y lo vuelvo a mirar (lo digo porque quizas has cambiado algo de la disposición de la tabla o a mi se me pasó algo por alto y si lo veo espero encontrar el error).  No cambies la pregunta actual, claro, sino las respuestas quedarán desincronizadas con la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: te dejo el link de la nueva pregunta, espero me puedas ayudar

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/560685/como-obtener-el-valor-de-un-selected-en-javascript/560730?noredirect=1#comment991559_560730

Comment: ah, vale, ya vi pasar esa pregunta y estuve mirándomela pero claro, tan solo pides como recuperar un valor selected y las respuestas que te daban ya eran correctas (si solo era eso).  Ahora que tengo más contexto me la miro mejor a ver.

Comment: tu código me funciona, pero tengo que actualizar a cada rato para que me vuelva a recuperar los registros correctos de otro campo, por ejemplo seleccionó un registro, me recupera los valores, modifico, le doy guardar, si quiero modificar otro registro, me deja el último registro guardado, no el que estoy seleccionando no sé si tenga otro detalle. En ocasiones no me recuperar los valores.

Comment: mmm... a simple vista no parece que mi código tenga culpa alguna.. me inclino más a pensar que es algo del formulario en si... ¿como lanzas la actualización de los datos a la base de datos?  ¿ajax?  ¿form normal?

Comment: sí, utilizo <div class="form-group"> o alguna forma que al guardar me refresque los datos

Comment: vamonos a un chat, porque esto puede ser largo...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139673/discussion-between-masterguru-and-andres-de-jesus).

Comment: (si vas al chat fíjate que abajo te pide hacer el login para que puedas interactuar, sino solo lo verás)

Comment: Probé este fragmento de código, y al parecer funciona correctamente. folio = tablaReportes.row($(this).closest('tr')).data()['folio'];

Comment: solo que ahora el código que me compartiste para recuperar el valor de un select, ya no funciona.

Comment: hola, ya pude corregir el error, de recuperar los valores del select, pero ahora cuando actualizo, no guarda los registros, podrías orientarme por favor.

Comment: Me alegro que lo arreglaras, me olvidé de responderte, la verdad (me pasa pocas veces, pero al tratar con tantas preguntas a la vez a veces me ocurre).  Para lo que pides ahora mejor crea una nueva pregunta con el formulario y lo que uses para enviarlo (si es tan solo un form con un post y un submit, o si usas ajax pon tambien el javsacript) para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Gracias realizaré un nuevo post.

Comment: le dejo el link de mi nueva pregunta

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/561482/problema-al-actualizar-datos-de-un-registro.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder setear el ingreso guardado en la base  de datos tienes que trabajar con el `id` del elemento, por ejemplo

```
      <select name="status" id="estatus" class="form-control" required>
            <option selected>eleccione una opción</option>
            <option value="1">Pendiente</option>
            <option value="2">En Proceso</option>
            <option value="3">Terminado</option>
      </select>
```

donde `value` debe ser el `id` del item en la base de datos.. Por ejemplo `id=1` corresponderia a pendiente en mi base de datos de datos.
En resumen para trabajar con select solo debes usar  el id...
Lo estas haciendo de la forma correcta.. pero al select no se le pasa el texto, se le pasa el value  y deberia quedarte algo asi `$("#estatus").val(idEstatus);`