# Como obtener el valor de un selected en Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo el siguiente problema, el cual me gustaría corregir. Tengo un pequeño crud con ventana modal, El problema que tengo, es al momento de recuperar los valores de mi selected, en ocasiones si me recupera los valores, en ocasiones me deja el último registro seleccionado. Quiero saber de qué manera puedo mejorar el código que utilizo para recuperar los valores del selected.

Este es mi código PHP donde tengo establecido mi selected

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cuadrilla" class="col-form-label">Cuadrilla</label>
<select name="cuadrilla" id="cuadrilla" class="form-control"required>
<option selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
<option value="1">Cuadrilla de Operación Ciudad</option>
<option value="2">Cuadrilla de Operación Mega sistema</option>
<option value="3">Cuadrilla de Drenajes</option>
<option value="4">Cuadrilla de Tomas tapadas</option>
<option value="5">Cuadrilla de Cloración</option>
<option value="6">Cuadrilla de Bacheo</option>
<option value="7">Cuadrilla de Contratos</option>
<option value="8">Otros</option>
</select>
</div>
```

De esta manera estoy recuperando los valores en desde JavaScript

```js
$("#cuadrilla option:contains(" + cuadrilla + ")").attr("selected","");
```

De esta manera compruebo si una variable está definida o no en el Script

```js
$cuadrilla = (isset($_POST['cuadrilla'])) ? $_POST['cuadrilla'] : '';
```

Les dejo captura de lo que sucede cuando intento recuperar los valores, en ocasiones los muestra, en ocasiones tengo que refrescar la página para poder ver los cambios. O incluso cuando intento realizar alguna modificación, me recupera los valores obtenidos de otros registros.

[image: Registros de mi crud]

No me recupera los valores obtenidos

[image: Crud]

Si selecciono una opción se queda establecido, pero no recupera los valores guardados de la BASE de datos, espero me puedan entender y ayudar, gracias.

[image: otro]

Comment: podrías agregar tu código de php?

Comment: @Sr1871 te refieres al código donde hago las consultas a la base de datos?

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el valor seleccionado en un elemento `select`, en jQuery mejor que en javascript puro (ya que estás usando jQuery), basta con usar el método `val()` directamente sobre el elemento:

```
$('#cuadrilla').val();
```

Si quisieras obtener no el valor sino algo distinto del elemento seleccionado, entonces sí tienes que tirar del selector para obtener el elemento `option` en sí. Por ejemplo, para obtener el texto de la opción seleccionada:

```
$('#cuadrilla option:selected').text();
```

**Nota**: No obstante, esto también funciona para obtener el valor, pero tienes que escribir más:

```
$('#cuadrilla option:selected').val();
```

**Referencia**:

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Comment: Hola ya intenté hacer lo que me comentases, pero sigue sin recuperar los valores.

Comment: Entonces falta bastante explicación. Para empezar, dónde es donde no te los "recupera", ¿en el javascript o en php?

Comment: En mi ventana modal de PHP cone esta instrucción si me lo recupera $("#cuadrilla option:contains(" + cuadrilla + ")").attr("selected", ""); Pero solo una vez, si quiero editar otro registro me deja el valor obtenido que obtuvo en un registro anterior.

Comment: PHP no tiene ventanas modales, y el código ese es jquery, osea, javascript. Quizá debas recargar el formulario usando ajax cada vez que pulses el botón para editar un registro. Tu consulta no está clara, falta que enseñes más código, pero aquí hay un montón de preguntas similares, sobre cómo hacer un modal para editar registros de un listado, y con ajax de por medio. Haz una búsqueda a ver si encuentras luz.

Comment: Tiene razón, tengo que presionar f5 para volver a recuperar un registro, porque si hago lo mismo con otros registros, me deja el ulitimo registro.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 problemas

- .attr("selected","") se usa para setear un atributo, no para obtenerlo. Para obtener el valor se hace sin el último parametro. attr("selected")
- El atributo selected no cambia cuando cambias el select. Este atributo es fijo, a menos que lo cambies ocupando attr(). Te dejo una demo para que veas que por más que cambies el select, el selected siempre es el primero

```js
function verSelected(){
 console.clear()
  $("option").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("selected"));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cuadrilla" class="col-form-label">Cuadrilla</label>
<select name="cuadrilla" id="cuadrilla" class="form-control"required>
<option selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
<option value="1">Cuadrilla de Operación Ciudad</option>
<option value="2">Cuadrilla de Operación Mega sistema</option>
<option value="3">Cuadrilla de Drenajes</option>
<option value="4">Cuadrilla de Tomas tapadas</option>
<option value="5">Cuadrilla de Cloración</option>
<option value="6">Cuadrilla de Bacheo</option>
<option value="7">Cuadrilla de Contratos</option>
<option value="8">Otros</option>
</select>
</div>
<button onclick="verSelected()">Mostar selected</button>
```

#### La solución

Para obtener el valor debes hacer $("#cuadrilla option:selected").val()

```js
function verSelected(){
let selected= $( "#cuadrilla option:selected").val();

console.log(selected);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cuadrilla" class="col-form-label">Cuadrilla</label>
<select name="cuadrilla" id="cuadrilla" class="form-control"required>
<option selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
<option value="1">Cuadrilla de Operación Ciudad</option>
<option value="2">Cuadrilla de Operación Mega sistema</option>
<option value="3">Cuadrilla de Drenajes</option>
<option value="4">Cuadrilla de Tomas tapadas</option>
<option value="5">Cuadrilla de Cloración</option>
<option value="6">Cuadrilla de Bacheo</option>
<option value="7">Cuadrilla de Contratos</option>
<option value="8">Otros</option>
</select>
<button onclick="verSelected()">Mostar selected</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @Yussef ya intenté hacer lo que me comentases, pero sigue sin recuperar los valores.